# Shutting down headless windows 10 from keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, shutdown

Two scenarios:

1. We sometimes connect to displays that go blank after startup.  We know that it is a display compatibilty problem because if we connect a compatible display, we can see the output.  What I'd like to do is to shut it down without having to hold down the power button.  It is a turnkey system where I have to find the key to unlock the cabinet and a second key to open the front of the computer to access the power button.  It would be easier if I could use a key sequence to shutdown.
2. When a demo has finished, very often the bigger fancier monitors are pinched and set up for other demos for the next day.  I know the machines are still on because I can see the flashing lights in the locked server room.  It is the end of the day, the key holder has gone home, how do I shut the machines down.

On Windows XP, I used to be able to type **Windows U U** and the machine would shut down.  Is there an equivalent sequence on Windows 10?  When I type **Windows U** it goes into the search.  I can't figure out what the key sequence is for the poweroff button in the menu.

**Edit**
One key sequence is **Windows Tab Down 5 times Return Down Return**.  Is there a better one?

Comment: `Win+X`, then `U` and `U`.  (or `R` as the final to Restart, `S` to sleep or `L` to log out)

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Shortcut to shutdown or restart Windows 10 in less than three keystrokes](https://superuser.com/questions/968672/shortcut-to-shutdown-or-restart-windows-10-in-less-than-three-keystrokes)

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate - should I delete it or can someone mark it as a duplicate and close it.

Comment: We can mark it as a dup and close it. Somebody can. I have little rep here. So I have no close votes `:(`

Answer (score 0):

## Is the box currently at a desktop? Or command-line?

### Desktop:

If you know for sure you're on the desktop, I'd run RUN via <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then let-go.  Assume run is up, and then simply type `CMD RETURN`.  Assume you've opened the command prompt.  Now you can just `shutdown /s /t 0` if you don't care about the programs shutting down immediately and not gracefully finishing their process...  If you want a graceful shutdown process...

### Command-line:

If you know you're a cursor sitting on a backdrop, then simply `Shutdown /s` will do the trick... remember without the `/t 0` tag you'll need to wait at least 60 seconds before it'll start to gracefully do the shutdown process... and could take a long time considering: Whether windows decides updates are going to be done; so if you wanted to go home early you could assume the machine is going to be off at this point.
Usually if you can hear the machine and it has platter drives it'll make a fuss while this thrashes the disk.

### BONUS:

If you wanted to get more out of the process, you could also set it up for a defrag and then to shutdown in one line.. but you'd have to trust your typing skills I suppose... also there is a way to shut down windows as to prepare it for quicker starting over time... This line would look like this...

```
defrag C: /B | shutdown /s /hybrid
```

Defrag, bells and whistles, then shutdown and prepare for fast boot! ( Using /C instead of C: will defrag ALL DRIVES!)

```
defrag /C /H /O /K | shutdown /s /hybrid
```

For SSDs add the `/L` tag to the mix for trimming... and you get the `|` by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> together.  The pipe truncates two commands to be done in succession.

Hope that does it for ya!

Comment: Would you trust yourself typing all that blind - there is no screen.

Comment: Yes, I don’t see why that would be a problem. Also, isn’t that the point of the question?

Comment: For any of those commands, you don’t actually have to launch the command prompt first; you can run the commands straight from the Run box.